# Laplace equation in a circle - where is my mistake

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We want to solve $r^2u''_{rr}+ru'_r+u''_{\theta \theta}=0$ where $0\leq \theta <2\pi$ and $0\leq r \leq 2$, given that $u(2,\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$.

I managed to work out a simple solution, but when I checked it, I saw that it does not agree with $r^2u''_{rr}+ru'_r+u''_{\theta \theta}=0$ and I'd like to know where is the mistake.

**My solution**

Let $u(r,\theta)=R(r)T(\theta)$. Then from $r^2u''_{rr}+ru'_r+u''_{\theta \theta}=0$ we have $\frac{r^2R''(r)+rR'(r)}{R(r)}=-\frac{T''(\theta)}{T(\theta)}$

On the left hand side we have a function of just $r$, on the right hand just $\theta$, so they must both be scalar $\frac{r^2R''(r)+rR'(r)}{R(r)}=-\frac{T''(\theta)}{T(\theta)}=\lambda$

From this we have $T''(\theta)+\lambda T(\theta)=0$, but since $u$ is periodic with respect to $\theta$ with period of $2\pi$, we must have $T(0)=T(2\pi)$ and $T'(0)=T'(2\pi)$. This is a sturm-liouville problem whos solution is given by:

$\lambda_k=k^2$ and $T_k(\theta)=A_k\cos(k\theta)+B_k\sin(k\theta)$. where $k=1,2,...$ and $T_0=1$.

But we also had $\frac{r^2R''(r)+rR'(r)}{R(r)}=\lambda=k^2$, so $r^2R''_k(r)+rR'_k(r)-k^2R_k(r)=0$

If we guess a solution $R(r)=r^\alpha$ then we have $\alpha(\alpha-1)\alpha-k^2=\alpha^2-k^2=0$ so $\alpha=\pm k$ and so $R_k(r)=C_kr^k+D_kr^{-k}$ when $k\neq 0$, and $R_0=C_0+D_0\ln(r)$.

So overall our solution will be of the form $u(r,\theta)=T_0(\theta)R_0(r)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}T_k(\theta)R_k(r)$ which equals to

$u(r,\theta)=C_0+D_0\ln(r)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[A_k\cos(k\theta)+B_k\sin(k\theta)](C_kr^k+D_kr^{-k})$

We impose another restriction that $\lim_{r\to 0}u(r,\theta)$ will be bounded. it will diverge to infinity or negative infinity. This can only happen when $D_0=0$ and $D_k=0$, so we have:

$u(r,\theta)=C_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[A_k\cos(k\theta)+B_k\sin(k\theta)]C_kr^k$

To make things simple, since we don't know either $A_k,B_k,C_k$ let's just say $C_k=1$ and find $A_k,B_k$ that all the conditions are met. So overall:

$u(r,\theta)=C_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[A_k\cos(k\theta)+B_k\sin(k\theta)]r^k$. but we also had a condition that $u(2,\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$. so

$u(2,\theta)=C_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[A_k\cos(k\theta)+B_k\sin(k\theta)]2^k=\cos(2\theta)$. This can only hold if $C_0=0$, $B_k=0$ for all $k$. In addition we must have $A_k=0$ when $k\neq 2$, and we must also have $2^2A_2=1$, so $A_2=\frac{1}{4}$ so my answer is:

$u(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{4}r^2\cos(2\theta)$. That's the solution I got.

Indeed it is true that $\lim_{r \to 0}u(r,\theta)=0$ is bounded.

And it is also true that $u(2,\theta)=\frac{1}{4}4\cos(2\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$. So these conditions are met.

However, we have $u'_r=\frac{1}{2}r\cos(2\theta)$, $u''_{rr}=\cos(2\theta)$ and $u''_{\theta \theta}=-r^2\cos(2\theta)$. so:

$r^2u''_{rr}+ru'_{r}+u''_{\theta \theta}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\cos(2\theta)$.

And it should be zero. So I'm really not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
u_{rr} = \frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta) \neq \cos (2\theta)
$$

Comment: That is heartbreaking.

Comment: I know I was going to comment. The question was great manipulation and general solving with separation of variables. But clear eyes makes it easy to detect the fault..I almost feel bad, and was hoping there was something deeper than that. We all been there!! Hence I gave a +1.